# SSRS - How can I determine which column is being accessed in a matrix control?

Tags: reporting-services

Here's the situation. The details cell of my matrix calls a custom function that determines an average of the values passed in. Those are converted to a percentage and returned by the Code.Function(). The matrix also has a subtotal column that averages out the columns as expected. Everything works great. However, the requirements changed and the matrix was converted to a hierarchy with summary 'roll-ups' if you will.

Now, when you collapse the rows, the data being averaged is still correct on the detail level. However, the same logic will no longer suffice for the subtotal column. Ideally, I would like to be able to determine in the function which column is currently be referenced and perform a different calculation based on that parameter. While there is a lot of talk about scope, which is the primary issue, I have no way to pass a string scope value into the function.

So the questions are:

1. Can you determine which column you are currently in at runtime?
2. Can you determine and pass the scope name you are in around in the report somehow? (passing a bool around doesn't help)

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard from your description to tell what exactly you are trying to do.

If I were to try something like this in SSRS, I would first look at trying to provide the information in the results of whatever stored proc is used, trying to keep the report as free from calculation as possible.

Comment: Actually, since the calculation is based on the user's interaction with the report, it needs to be done on-the-fly. I'll attempt to clarify. Consider the data in matrix as an unnatural hierarchy. When the report loads, all rows are collapsed. There are five columns calculated from the data and a sixth that is an average of the previous five. The sixth row is providing incorrect totals at all levels until the user drills all the way down to the lowest level. I'm attempting to modify the custom code that performs the calculation to take it's 'scope' into account and provide the correct data.

Comment: Given the the scope and level of the row are built in Miscellaneous functions you still need a way to figure out the value of the control that shows/hides the group.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm explaining this properly. I have everything I need from the data. What I'm attempting to do is control a matrix-generated sum column. If you put an expression in for your details cell, it will be used in the auto-generated sum column. The math inside the expression (a custom VB function) needs to change if the scope changes. I just want to be able to determine the scope or column inside the function (written to the Code tab after right clicking the gray area of the report and choosing Properties).